# winform or wpf for entity framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, entity-framework

I want to know which one is the best natural choice while working with SQL and Entity framework, c# Winform or the WPF? Assume that skilled resources available for both the technologies (Winforms and WPF).

Comment: EF allows you to access db and Winform/WPF are technologies for layout. They are just 2 different things. This question does not make any sense.

Comment: This is not a question. I am asking for suggestions for which GUI framework to use. And many people have suggested also (Noich,Dhaval, marc_s). If someone cannot help he has no right to make negative comments. Based on the suggestions I have decided to go with WPF.

Comment: I can't help you because what you are asking is out of sense and for that I have a full right to give negative comments. Decision whether to use winforms or wpf is not dependant in any way on where are you taking your data from.

Comment: Perhaps if we look at it this way - "Has anyonw encountered integration issues when working with EF and WinForms / EF and WPF? Are there any technical reasons to prefer one over the other?"
This question will appear less opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with both, I strongly recommend `WPF`, since it gives you a far better code/UI separation. Using `MVVM` makes the code more readable and easier to maintain (and read).
SQL and EF don't care how the layers above are implemented, it's your choice alone.

Answer (score 8):

Entity Framework **doesn't care** which UI technology you use on top of it.

There's no *natural choice* - use whatever you're comfortable with and whichever works for your needs

Comment: I am concerned about the data binding etc. Winforms use adapter classes and use SQL classes to run the query and retrieve the data which can be bound to Winforms controls. This binding is not so easy with EF in winforms. Does WPF make it easy to do data bindings with EF?

Comment: @JavedAnsari: as I said - **EF doesn't care** - it's the GUI technology that should dictate your choice. Yes, WPF of course is more modern, and probably has better databinding support (haven't used it myself, so I can't really say from experience). So if you have the WPF skills and know-how - go with WPF ! EF works just as fine with WPF as with Winforms .....

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want someone's advice who have used data binding in both (WPF and WinForms) using EF. As my application would be havily using back end sql db.

Comment: @JavedAnsari I (and most likely marc_s too) have had plenty of experience with both WPF and WF binding. It does not matter. Whichever you are more comfortable with go with that one. With a proper [n-teir architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) you can swap out your UI with 0 changes to what you do in EF and if you keep your layers loosely coupled you can swap out EF with a different tech (maybe NHibernate or something totally non-SQL based) and not need to make any changes to your UI.

Comment: It doesn't matter. EF is completely unrelated to whatever UI platform you choose.

Answer (score 0):

EF not dependand any one like if you used winfrm or WPF. but there is a difference between winform and WPF.

if you want to know then you can use the mentioned link [Click here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/wpf-vs-winforms/)

If you want better Presentation of your application then I would recommand you to go with WPF.

Comment: Thaks for reply. How about data binding in WPF using EF? Winform is not good in data binding with EF. isn't it? I am mainly concerned about ease of data binding.

Comment: I think the main advantage of WPF over Windows Forms is not data binding, but data templating: the type of the data can determine the UI that is instantiated, and this UI can be defined in a concise, easy, declarative way using XAML. This takes polymorphic behaviour to the UI level, without the need to implement custom frameworks for dynamic UI generation.

Comment: Personally, I like the loose coupling between the UI and the business layer which is enforced when using WPF and the MVVM pattern. While in Windows Forms, data binding is optional, in WPF it is the main mechanism to connect the UI layer to what is below it, and if one uses the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, it effectively becomes the only mechanism. This forces one to think very clearly about what the application can do, allows to change the UI without any side effects in the lower layers, and allows to test the application independent of the UI.